# Installed SELinux on Ubuntu 14.04 and system is not bootable now

Tags: 14.04, selinux

I was trying to learn a bit about SELinux on my Ubuntu 14.04 and did not realize that it already had AppArmor which SELinux un-installs during its own installation process.

I installed two packages `selinux-utils` and `selinux` (in that order). During the installation of `selinux` I was promoted to reboot in the bash shell. When I hit the enter key it proceeded further and said some post installation script failed.

I then tried to reboot and the initial error was `/` being a read-only partition. So I went into Grub and edited the `ro` parameter to the kernel and changed it to `rw`. After it was able to create a directory `/selinux` but now I am getting a different error which I captured below (this is from trying to boot into single user mode)

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... /sbin/load_policy: Can't load policy: No such device
Warning: SELinux policy load failed, continuing
mount: mounting none on /selinux failed: No such device
Warning: Unable to mount /selinux
done.
```

There are some further messages related to `plymouth-upstart-bridge`. Finally there is one more error message (not sure if this is related to SELinux)

```
[drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared fifo underrun on pch transcoder
```

I am guessing now the problem is this line `mount: mounting none on /selinux failed: No such device`

From my grub I can see that `/` is on `(hd0,5)` and there is an `selinux` directory under `/`. What I cannot understand is whether selinux is trying to mount some device to `/selinux` or does it think that `/selinux` should be a device by itself?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a work around. I got into grub boot menu and removed two kernel parameters `security=selinux selinux=1` from below

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic root=UUID=e2c77541-5134-497a-a180-529bfd83f38f ro  quiet splash security=selinux selinux=1 $vt_handoff
```

This allowed me to boot into multiuser system and then I uninstalled `selinux` and updated the grub configuration so that future boots won't pass the `selinux` parameters to the kernel.